# dns problem on my mac?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, svn, mac

I have a subversion installation running on a remote server which I manage myself. It worked just fine for a few weeks already and there were no changes in DNS or subversion configuration, but since yesterday I'm unable to commit/update anything. The error message I'm getting is:

> Olgas-MacBook-Pro:ingenix olgary$ svn
>   update
>       svn: OPTIONS of 'http://mysvnhost/myproject/trunk':
>   Could not resolve hostname
>   `svn.logicaldesign.ru': Host not found
>   (http://mysvnhost)

When I try to ping the host I get:

> Olgas-MacBook-Pro:ingenix olgary$ ping
>   mysvnhost ping: cannot resolve
>   mysvnhost: Unknown host

The situation is that from OTHER computers everything is working just fine, no problems at all. Seems the problem is on my end... I've tried to reboot, execute "dscacheutil -flushcache" command, but nothing helped. Have no idea what else I can do. Any help will be greatly appreciated... Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you a hosts file referencing an old ip address?

[Here's how to edit the hosts file](https://superuser.com/questions/90700/changing-hosts-file-on-snow-leopard).

Comment: Hi Cris! I did not have any mentioning of my domain in my hosts file, so what I did is added a row for it. I know this may be just a temporary workaround, but at least I can continue my work and commit files to svn. Thank you for the hint!